# wp_page_menu not working right?

Tags: menus, navigation

I try to create simple menu in custom theme. WordPress version is 3.9.1 So I taking code from here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu, just change menu and container class / id for better debuging.

```
<?php
            wp_nav_menu(
                array(
                    'theme_location'  => '',
                    'menu'            => '',
                    'container'       => 'div',
                    'container_class' => 'container_class',
                    'container_id'    => 'container_id',
                    'menu_class'      => 'menu_class',
                    'menu_id'         => 'menu_id',
                    'echo'            => true,
                    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                    'before'          => '',
                    'after'           => '',
                    'link_before'     => '',
                    'link_after'      => '',
                    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                    'depth'           => 0,
                    'walker'          => ''
                )
            );
        ?>
```

But it creates this code:

```
<div class="menu_class">
    <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2">
            <a href="http://localhost/?page_id=2">Пример страницы</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Instead of expected this:

```
<div id="container_id" class="container_id">
    <ul id="menu_id" class="menu_class">
        <li class="page_item page-item-2">
            <a href="http://localhost/?page_id=2">Пример страницы</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What i do wrong? Thank you.

**UPDATED**
I already has this code at fuctions.php:

```
<?php

function bd_setup() {
    register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu' ) );
}

add_action( 'init', 'bd_setup' );
```

**SOLVED**
After creation Menu in Appearance->Menu and assignation it in Appearance->Menu->Manage Locations I got expected code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code it works perfectly fine for me, to give output as:

```
<div class="container_class" id="container_id">
<ul class="menu_class" id="menu_id">
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-154"><a href="http://www.ohitsfunny.com/category/funny/">Funny</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-159"><a href="http://www.ohitsfunny.com/category/jokes-2/">Jokes</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-156"><a href="http://www.ohitsfunny.com/category/love/">Love</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-155"><a href="http://www.ohitsfunny.com/category/motivational/">Motivational</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-157"><a href="http://www.ohitsfunny.com/category/political/">Political</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-158"><a href="http://www.ohitsfunny.com/category/news/">News</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I think you might be missing the argument 'theme_location', and founding no menu at that location the fallback "wp_page_menu" is being executed. Which doesn't use the classes you mentioned in the call to "wp_nav_menu".

In case you don't know what a 'theme_location' could be:

```
function register_my_new_menu() {
  register_nav_menus( array(
    'custom-menu'   =>  __( 'Custom Menu', 'the-bootstrap' )
    // Theme Location: custom-menu
    // Menu Name: Custom Menu
    // Create and assign a menu to this location in Dashboard->Menus
  ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_new_menu' );
```

Apologies, if I get to basics that you already know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already has similar code at functions.php. I think problem somwhere in Appearance -> Menu. After installation dedfault menu was not edited (created?). Is there any way to render right code just immediately after installing wordpress?

Comment: Aha, sawed answer in your comment :) "Create and assign a menu to this location in Dashboard->Menus". I  
assume that it is normal practise in WP to create and assign menu for each theme?

Comment: Advantage of WP is it's robust dashboard. So, we should care to use it at it's full. Yes, we create custom menu locations and assign a menu to it from the Menus Admin.